# PHP Memory usage keeps growing with each loop

Tags: php, windows, memory, xampp, bigdata

I have a foreach loop that happens to do more than 1 million itteration and does a few tests and database queries. The problem is when I tracks the memory usage, it keeps growing with about 500Ko, with that rate it exceeds the memory maximum size of 128M, I used unset on my variables but that does not work, I am careful not to change the maximum memory usage size.
Any ideas how to fix this problem ?
By the way, I'm using XAMPP 3.2.1 on Windows 7.

> Update to use generators

```
public function import()
{
    $var = 0;

    $filename = 'path';

    if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
            foreach ($this->readLines($filename) as $data)
            {

                if (strpos($data[2], 'string') !== false)
                {

                    // codes and DB queries

                }
                else
                {
                    if (strpos($data[1], '.png') !== false)
                    {
                        // code
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        if ($data[0] != "")
                        {
                            switch($var)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    // code
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    // code
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    // code
                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    // code
                                    break;

                                case 4:
                                    // code
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    // code
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            // code
                        }
                    } 
                } 

            }
            fclose($handle);
            return //route;
        }

        {
            return //route;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return //route;
    }

    return //route;
}
```

My generator looks like :

```
function readLines($filename)
{
    $file= fopen($filename, 'r');
    try
    {
        while (($line= fgetcsv($file, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            yield $line;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well we can ___guess___ at what your code is doing, and what array you might be extending in every iteration of your loop, or you might show some some of your code so that we can ___tell___ you

Comment: Well you've posted some code now, but looks like you've stripped out anything that might be using memory, replacing it with `//  code`

Comment: Note that you're opening the file both in your generator, and in your main function code.... you only need it open once (in the generator, since you're using that to actually read the file)

Comment: And unless you're injecting exceptions into your generator (but not catching them) you don't need the try/finally in your generator, because fgetscv() will never throw an exception

Comment: Thank you Mark, my code got messing with all the changes I made trynna figure out the source of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem, and it's my bad cause I didn't read the Laravel documentation.

> By default, Laravel keeps a log in memory of all queries that have been run for the current request. However, in some cases, such as when inserting a large number of rows, this can cause the application to use excess memory. To disable the log, you may use the disableQueryLog method

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: This helped, and Laravel Telescope also contributed, had to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Generators.
http://php.net/manual/de/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: From reading the documentation, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks Fox, I'll try it, and let you know

Comment: Using a generator didn't really help much, I used it on the loop that reads the CSV, but memory usage kept increasing til it reaches the 128M allowed. I'm still looking for a solution, I'll post my function and the generator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the cause of your memory leak. Unset your php variables. I once leaked in a loop because the database class i was using stored all the queries executed in an array which grew in size with each query

Comment: I used unset on all my variables, Now I'm checking the database queries, by the way, I use Laravel's ORM, Eloquent